# I think beforeSend function works incorrectly on chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, loading

When I send an "async=false" request using ajax, is it possible to show a loading sign for the duration of the response. And yes, alert message appears but I've never seen the loading sign.

By the way, there is no any problem for Firefox. Actually it works in chrome too when I change this async value to true.

Any idea?

```
var HttpUtil = {

get : function(url, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    this.ajaxCall('GET', url, this.defaultContentType, null, false, false, onSuccess, onFailure);
},

post : function(url, request, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    var showSuccessMsg = url.indexOf('/filter') < 0;
    this.ajaxCall('POST', url, null, JSON.stringify(request), showSuccessMsg, true, onSuccess, onFailure);
},

postFormData : function(url, request, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    this.ajaxCall('POST', url, false, request, true, true, onSuccess, onFailure);
},

put : function(url, request, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    this.ajaxCall('PUT', url, null, JSON.stringify(request), true, true, onSuccess, onFailure);
},

delete : function(url, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    this.ajaxCall('POST', url, null, null, true, true, onSuccess, onFailure);
},

ajaxCall : function(type, url, contentType, request, showSuccessMsg, showLoading, onSuccess, onFailure) { 
    if(contentType == null){
        contentType = 'application/json';
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: url,  
        type: type, 
        data: request,
        async: false,
        contentType : contentType,
        processData : false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(showSuccessMsg){
                ShowMessage.success("Success!", function onConfirm(){
                    onSuccess(data);
                });
            }else{
                onSuccess(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            if (onFailure instanceof Function) {
                onFailure(error);
            } else {
                if(error.responseJSON){
                    ShowMessage.error(error.responseJSON.status, error.responseJSON.message);
                }else{
                    ShowMessage.error(JSON.stringify(error));   
                }
            }
        },
        beforeSend : function() {
            if(showLoading){
                //$('.loading1').css("z-index","11111");
                $('.loading1').css("display","block");
                //alert("1");
            }
        },
        complete : function() {
            if(showLoading){
                //$('.loading1').css("z-index","-1");
                $('.loading1').css("display","none");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Try adding delay of 1 ms in before send :

```
beforeSend : function() {
            if(showLoading){
                //$('.loading1').css("z-index","11111");
           setTimeout(function(){
             $('.loading1').css("display","block");
           }, 1);

                //alert("1");
            }
        },
```

Comment: It works like this but it is not closing this time :)

Comment: It doesn't close because it doesn't enter the complete method due to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

By the way it works this way, but it's working late ofcourse :(

```
beforeSend : function() {
            if(showLoading){
                $('.loading').css("display","block");
            }
        },
        complete : function() {
            if(showLoading){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.loading').css("display","none");
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
```